# how can i fix the formatting my log file from plink?

Tags: putty

When I used to run Putty I got a nicely formatted log from the command
Now.. I am forced to use plink instead... the log file produced...

> plink.exe -ssh -sshlog C:\putty.log  -P .. etc etc

Looks all garbled..eg:

> Incoming packet #0x155, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
>     00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 18 46 69 6e 69 73 68 20 63  ........Finish c
>     00000010  68 65 63 6b 69 6e 67 20 63 6f 6c 75 6d 6e 73 0a  hecking columns.
>   Incoming packet #0x156, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
>     00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 10 45 72 72 6f 72 73 20 63  ........Errors c
>     00000010  6f 75 6e 74 3a 20 30 0a                          ount: 0.
>   Incoming packet #0x157, type 94 / 0x5e (SSH2_MSG_CHANNEL_DATA)
>     00000000  00 00 01 00 00 00 00 15 53 74 61 72 74 20 73 61  ........Start sa
>     00000010  76 69 6e 67 20 62 75 6e 63 68 65 73 0a           ving bunches.

How can I get my original nicely presented log data?